# MKMapPoint is not convertible to Void error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I am trying to draw a path on MKMapView from list of coordinates but I get two errors.
This is code (error lines have comments):

```
var routes = [CoordVO]();
        routes.append(pn)
        routes.appe...

        var a = UInt(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)) * UInt(routes.count)
        var pointArr = malloc(a)

        for var idx = 0; idx < routes.count; idx++ {

            var obj = routes[idx]

            var workingCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D!
            workingCoordinate.latitude=obj.lat
            workingCoordinate.longitude=obj.lng

            var point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate)
            pointArr[idx] = point; // MKMapPoint is not convertible to Void

        }

        var routeLine = MKPolyline(points: pointArr, count: routes.count) // Void is not identical to MKMapPoint

        self.mapView.addOverlay(routeLine)

        free(pointArr);
```

Comment: Two side notes: 1) malloc is being done with sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) but code is putting MKMapPoint structs in the array.  Change it to sizeof(MKMapPoint).  2) MKPolyline has another convenience initializer `coordinates:count:` that takes an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D so you don't need to convert to MKMapPoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the definition of the `MKPolyline` init method:

```
init!(points points: UnsafeMutablePointer<MKMapPoint>, count count: Int)
```

It needs an `UnsafeMutablePointer<MKMapPoint>`, but with `malloc` you create an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, that causes the problem.